# Subversion merge did not merge a file

Tags: svn

There is a file, fileA, that exists in the trunk but does not exist in our development branch.  A developer accidentally performed an 'svn add' of this file into our branch instead of performing an 'svn merge' of fileA from the trunk.  What I did was performed an 'svn delete' of this file in our development branch.  Then I performed a merge from the trunk in an effort to sync our branch with the trunk.  For some reason, fileA was NOT merged over to our branch.  When I did an 'svn status' on the branch's directory, fileA has a '?' next to it.  I then tried to 'rm' what i suspect was a residual copy of the file after I did the 'svn delete' originally.  How can I get fileA into the branch now?  'svn merge' does not merge anything from the trunk now!  I need to ensure that the history of the file is also merged over.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-D

Comment: what about `svn copy` that file from trunk to your branch?

Answer (score 0):

Merge again using the `--ignore-ancestry` option. This lets the merge command ignore any tracked merge info and just compare the two files line by line.